# Как удалить раздел вместе с товарами из магазина написать функцию ( питон)

Tags: python

Как удалить раздел вместе с товарами из магазина написать функцию ( питон).
Я начинающий не могу понять как это сделать.

```
#Есть магазин
shop = {
    "мучное": {
        "хлеб": 200
    },
    "молочное":{
        "молоко":50
    }
}
# добавление товара и раздела

def add_products(user_group, shop=shop, **products):
    if user_group in shop:
        shop[user_group].update(products)

    elif user_group not in shop:
        shop.update({user_group:{}})
        shop[user_group].update(products)
        

    else:
        return "Ошибка"

        return shop
# вывод всех разделов и товаров
def print_all_products(shop=shop):
    for group, array in shop.items():
        print ("Раздел: " + group)
        for product, price in array.items():
            print(product + " - " + str(price))

# удаление товаров из выбранного раздела
def del_products(user_group, shop=shop, **products):
    if user_group in shop:
        shop[user_group].clear()

# вывод товаров из определенного раздела 
def print_all_product_user_group(user_group, shop=shop):
    for key, value in shop[user_group].items():
        print(key + ': ' + str(value))
```

Сложность возникла в :

1. Удаление раздела
2. Функция снижения или повышения цены на выбранный  товар

пытался так

```
def update_price(new_price, shop=shop):
    for products, price in shop.items():
        shop.update({products:price+new_price})
        return shop
```

ошибка

```
  File "c:\python programms\shopnew.py", line 41, in update_price
    shop.update({products:price+new_price})
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str'
```

Спасибо за помощь.
Отредактировал под свой код все работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в цикле нужен еще один уровень вложенности, сейчас вы пытаетесь прибавть изменение цены к словарю `мучное` и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def corrprice(mag, razdel, product, n):
        mag[razdel][product] += n
        return mag
```

Функция коррекции цены.

Comment: @АнтонСмирнов, никак. не предназначены комментарии для этого. надо вставить форматированный текст — дополняйте текст вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

```
def delete(shop, razdel): 
    del shop[razdel] 
    return shop
```

del shop["мучное"] - удаление раздела "мучное".
Общий вид - del dictionary[key]

Comment: код пишем через функцию def и в ней код.  Нужно повысить цену на выбранный товар например раздел мучное хлеб на 10 р

Comment: def delete(dict, key): 
    del dict[key]
    return dict

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос